# Trying to get matplotlib/numpy to work. Have tried different solutions and out of ideas

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to run a basic matplotlib script to ensure that everything is working. The program is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.arrange(0,5,0.1);
y=np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

But when I run "python a.py" in the terminal I am getting the error
that the numpy module has no attribute 'arrange'.

I uninstalled numpy and matplotlib and reinstalled them. First numpy, then matplotlib through the ubuntu repository but I am still getting this error. I can't figure out what is wrong. Am I getting an incomplete installation or something? I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: .. does [`np.arange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) work?

Comment: not `arrange`. Right: `arange`.

Comment: That did work! It returned no errors. No plot was shown however. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Voting to close as typo.

Comment: put at final: `plt.show()`

Comment: OK. Also figured out the other thing just had to use pylab.show()

Comment: You used `matplotlib.pyplot`, so It must be `plt.show()`

Answer (score 3):

The method name is `arange`, not `arrange`.

Also, after using `plt.plot(...)`, you need to call `plt.show()` to draw the plot.